# Solve this equation for $t$

Tags: polynomials, self-learning

I am having trouble solving this equation for $t$ ($s$ is just a paremeter):
$$s = t+\frac{t^3}{3}$$

Comment: So it is a cubic polynomial equation.  Solving it in terms of cube roots and square roots (see e.g. [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano's_formula)) is possible, but in many cases solving it numerically is more useful/efficient.  There are many posts here about solving cubic polynomial equations generally.  What is your application?

Comment: If you look at the solution on wolfram alpha ( https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=t%2Bt%5E3%2F3%3Ds ) you'll see it's not pretty. The wikipedia page on cubic equations says how to solve it, but it is a bit involved. As you can see in the wolfram solution, $s = 3 (3 n^3 + n), t = 3 n$, are the integer solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The number of a real solutions for the equation $x^3+3px+2q=0$ is in relation to the sign of discriminant $D=q^2+p^3$.

Above equation will have $3$ real distinct solutions if $D<0$.

Above equation will have $1$ real solution ($1$ real and $2$ complex roots) if $D>0$.

For $D=0$, above equation will have $1$ real solution ($1$ real root with multiplicity three) in the case $p = q = 0$; or $2$ real solutions (a single and a double real root) in the case $p^3=-q^2 \neq 0$.